# Python re.sub(): Replacing a char between two different categories

Tags: python, regex, json

I want to convert a nested bracketted structure into the JSON formatted square bracketted structure.

```
input_string = '( np ( ap ( !b ( 显微 ) ) !np ( !n ( 解剖学 ) )'    
output_string = '[ "np", [ "ap", [ "!b" , "显微" ] ] [ "!np", [ "!n" , "解剖学" ] ] ]'
```

so, I need to make three changes.

1. Replace the pattern **english_letter ( english letter** with **"english_letter", [ "english_letter"**
   for example, `ap ( !b`    ->   `"ap", [ "!b"`
2. Replace the pattern **english_letter ( chinese letter** with **"english_letter", "chinese_letter"**
   for example, `!b ( 显微` -> `"!b" , "显微"`
3. Replace the pattern **) english_letter** with  **] [ "english_letter"**

I cannot figure out how to work it out, especially the second one. I've tried out classifying letters into two lists, i.e. Chinese and English, but I have no idea how to match the pattern of **english_letter ( chinese letter**

Comment: In place of `chinese letter` use `not english letter, not space, not other chars`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the last `]` of your `output_string` is a typo, because this bracket does not match any opening bracket. Here's an attempt, does this fulfill your requirements? It should at least get you started. It certainly can be optimized.

```
>>> input_string = re.sub('\(', '[', input_string)
>>> input_string
'[ np [ ap [ !b [ 显微 ) ) !np [ !n [ 解剖学 ) )'
>>> input_string = re.sub('\)', ']', input_string)
>>> input_string
'[ np [ ap [ !b [ 显微 ] ] !np [ !n [ 解剖学 ] ]'
>>> input_string = re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z!]+)', r'"\1",', input_string)
>>> input_string
'[ "np", [ "ap", [ "!b", [ 显微 ] ] "!np", [ "!n", [ 解剖学 ] ]'
>>> input_string = re.sub(r'(",\ )\[\ ([^\x00-\x7F]+)',r'\1"\2"' ,input_string)
>>> input_string
'[ "np", [ "ap", [ "!b", "显微" ] ] "!np", [ "!n", "解剖学" ] ]'
```

Comment: I was thinking about similar solution in few steps.

Comment: @timgeb yes, you're right. I didn't realize the last bracket ']' does not match a opening bracket. now I should add an extra opening bracket in front of "!np". Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option to use.

```
>>> original = '( np ( ap ( !b ( 显微 ) ) !np ( !n ( 解剖学 ) )'
>>> modified = re.sub(r'([^() ]+)', '"\\1",', original)
>>> modified = re.sub(r'(", )\( ("[^\x00-\x7F]+"),', '\\1\\2', modified)
>>> modified = modified.replace('(', '[').replace(')', ']')
```

Output

```
[ "np", [ "ap", [ "!b", "显微" ] ] "!np", [ "!n", "解剖学" ] ]
```